# DDD: should I have data in entities or should I get the data from the repository

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, ddd-repositories

Let's say that I have a Seller aggregate with 2 collections: product for sale and sold-out products. I also have a Product aggregate with status (for sale or sold-out). Should I have the two collections in the Seller aggregate if I don't need them for any invariant and only use them for easier access from the UI (only for reading) or should I get this data from the database from the repository by filtering the products by status and seller?

Comment: "use them for easier access from the UI" ; do you mean read access?

Comment: Yes I use them only for reading but I can also get all sold out product when I filter the products by status and seller?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I have the two collections in the Seller aggregate if I don't need them for any invariant (...)

If you don't need them for business validation, don't put them in the domain model.

> (...) should I get this data from the database from the repository by filtering the products by status and seller?

You should not use the repository for querying your application state. You should write a mediator that does translation directly from database to DTO.

See this other question for details on why and how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71608061/6092856

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's ok to retrieve an **Aggregate** (with  your 2 collections into it) from a **Repository**.

After calling your **Repository**, you should translate the **Aggregate** properties into a DTO to return the data to your UI.

Comment: I only need them for reading from the UI to display them on the screen.

Comment: Ok @manfrom, thank you, I modify my answer. Feel free to ask if it's not clear.