# Maintaning isolation between modules in Django monolith

Tags: python, django, architecture, domain-driven-design

In our company, we have a monolith. Right now is not that big but we are already seeing some problems with the isolation between the modules we have. Our setup is pretty similar to other Django backends: we have a common User model and another UserProfile model where we store additional information about the user. As an additional thing, we also have a company model to group our users by company.

These models are shared across all the modules, at least they are coupled as foreign keys in the models of the rest of the modules. They are contained in a `companies` module, where we have our business rules about how many users a company can have, invariants in their profile, etc. I think this is fine because we usually just do simple and fast join by user ID or filter by it, so we treat this dependency as read-only so we don't skip any business rules/boundaries related to the companies module.

My problem comes when, for instance, some `moduleA`, needs to trigger an application service in `moduleB`. For instance, let's say `moduleB` needs to access a resource in `moduleA`. The code would be something like:

```py
# The GetResourceInterface is defined in module A!
from moduleA import GetResourceInterface

class AServiceInModuleB:
    # We use dependency injection
    
    def __init__(service: GetResourceInterface):
        pass
```

Now this is a direct import from a different module, so it seems we are breaking the boundaries (even though is not the domain layer, is just the application layer). Nonetheless, sometimes we don't return DTOs from services because our domain objects are not that big or complex to define DTOs (we would just be duplicating a class with a different name but almost the same attributes). So in those cases, we would indeed be breaking the isolation.

A possible alternative we have thought about is to contact other modules using their REST API (we define an API for every module because we also use it in our clients). In that case, the code would be something like:

```py
# The name could be different (not sure which for now)
from dependencies import ModuleAConnectorInterface

class AServiceInModuleB:
    def __init__(connector: ModuleAConnectorInterface):
         pass
```

The main advantage I think here is that the dependencies between modules are way more explicit to read in the file structure and in the code. Also, if more operations are needed from `moduleA`, they can be added to that connector too.

What possible problems do we see in this approach? The additional overhead of an additional HTTP request. This would be authenticated with JWT because that's pretty easy and fast to verify. The HTTP request would possibly just be made locally because even though we have a monolith, we have around 10 or 15 replicas of the Django app running the web server. Also, we had a bit of a worry about having a chatty architecture, where every service makes a lot of calls to other services, but honestly, this is a minor concern because we don't see it as a real thing happening with our current/future requirements.

So, my question is, is this a valid solution? Are we totally overengineering this isolation of boundaries? Our main concern is that we come from a messy monolith with no boundaries, and now we are remaking the app and the team is growing. For the sake of simplicity, we are keeping a mono-repository with our monolith, but every team is going to own a couple of modules, so we want to avoid interdependencies/breaking other people's code/stopping other people from refactoring/etc.

Sorry for the long text and let me know if you need any additional information to answer the question! Thanks! :D

Note: not sure if useful, we are using DDD, so we try to define clear bounded contexts with different domains and isolated data structures to represent the domain.**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

##### Hypothesis

I'll make an hypothesis for my answer that you are trying to implement some DDD boundary separation within a monolithic application, which implies you have a single monolithic persistence store (a single RDBMS or NoSQL database store) and you are not *yet* moving towards a microservice architecture (with separate API and persistence backend per bounded context).

##### The purpose of the domain layer

I'd like to express a few facts about the *purpose* of the domain layer in DDD.

The domain layer is where you implement code that validates that you do not violate some invariant business rules. The domain layer is useful when changing your application state, but if all state changing operations go through the domain layer, no read-only operation can violate a business rule. So calling the domain layer from read-only use cases is a waste of resources.

When changing the state of an entity, you don't need to check for every invariants of every entities in your model. This is why the domain layer is split into small chucks of business models, called bounded context. When changing an entity state, you only check invariants that are susceptible to get violated by the change, within the bounded context. Sometimes you need to check some invariants accross multiple contexts but this has to be an exception as it will require some complex multi-phase commit patterns.

Now onto your questions.

##### Should you import GetResourceInterface

Your current implementation is to import an external class that reads the module A context for data. Now it is unclear to me as to whether this class returns domain layer objects or presentation layer objects. Though you specify that sometimes you are publishing your aggregates as DTO. You can read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71606804/ddd-how-to-use-mediator-pattern-to-push-aggregates/71608061#71608061) on why this can cause problems. Briefly:

The domain model of the resource is tailored to ensure no business rule is violated when changing the resource state. It is not tailored for read only operations, either within nor outside of the resource owning bounded context. This is why it is recommended that you separate your resource read methods in two different classes:

- A repository (interface domain layer, implementation persitence layer), reads the resource state for state-chaging operations, such as HTTP PATCH requests. It returns domain objects that you can mutate, check for business rules, then persist back to the store.
- A mediator (interface presentation layer, implementation persistence layer), reads the resource state for read-only operation, such as HTTP GET request. It directly maps the database to a DTO without projecting to the domain layer, as you don't need to check for business invariants when querying your state.

Then instead of importing your generic `GetResourceInterface` from other modules, you can *at least* import the mediator. The drawback of this approach is that you create a dependency from the domain layer towards the presentation layer, which might cause circular dependency or other problems. Also, changing the presentation interface of your resource could break your other modules domain layers, which is a risk you might not want to take.

This is why the most viable approach in your situation is to have a different class, in `moduleB`, that reads the state of the resource directly from the database and returns a moduleB specific representation of the resource state. This model can differ both from the domain model and the DTO used in `moduleA`. Having different representations, in the business layer, of the same concept for each bounded context is actually the recommended way to implement bounded contexts and is called [polysemic domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html). Beware thouh, that you are creating a dependency between moduleB domain model and the persistence schema of the resource. This requires you to restrain to bounded contexts sharing the same persistence infrastructure and maintained by the same team.

##### Should you call another module API via HTTP

*Short answer: never ever try to do that.*

You are putting additional stress on your network infrastructure. Whenever you want to shift towards a more scalable microservice architecture you'll be having a synchronous dependency between two services. Instead of multiplying the system's availability you'll divide it, as your service B will be unable to process request whenever service A falls. Your infrastructure will crumble like a game of dominoes, because service B will eventually have some dependents that will also stop working whenever service A crashes. And so on ...

##### How to move towards a microservice

As stated, the solution presented above is only valid when the different modules share the same persistence backend and are maintained by a single team with good internal communication. However it will inevitably come a time when changing a persistence schema for the resource will not be correctly propagated to other bounded context or you'll want to go towards a microservice architecture with each bounded context having their own dedicared persistence backend. `moduleA` and `moduleB` will then become `serviceA` and `serviceB`.

The solution to this is to extend the concept of polysemic to the whole application stack. Have a representation of the resource in `serviceB` persistence store. This representation can be simpler than the one you have in `serviceA` because some details are only useful when changing the resource state. For instance, you may flatten some relationships. Then you will need to synchronize the data from the source of truth in `serviceA` to the copy in `serviceB` asynchronously.